# Interecepting navigation in webview Windows Runtime application

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8.1

I have this code for NDA reasons i will replace all sensitive information with a word domain.

WebViewPage.xaml

```
<Page
   x:Class="Domain.Views.WebViewPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="Domain.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
    <WebView Name="webView" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

WebViewPage.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   string url = "http://domain.com/music";
   webView.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));

   webView.NavigationStarting += webView_NavigationStarting;
   webView.NavigationCompleted += webView_NavigationCompleted;
}

void webView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
}

void webView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{   
}
```

When i open the page the url is loaded. i get the page i wanted.
Than i have to download music from that page when i click that i get the folowing .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a4pN.jpg

I belive this is because of the javascript

```
 var downloadTrack = function () {
                Tracking.recordTrackDownload(track, $scope.isPromoTrack(track));
                top.location.href = 'domain://musicSelected' + '?track=' + encodeURIComponent(angular.toJson(track));
                Audio.stop();
            };
```

the link is not a valid link and thats why it shows that you need an app for opening it.

I need information from that link is there a way to read that link.

in android i would do it like this

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            progressLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progressLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view,
                                    int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            progressLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            reportError(errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String loadingUrl) {
            if (loadingUrl.startsWith("domain://")) {
                return handleDomainUrl(loadingUrl);
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

EDIT:

I have found this example on MSDN. But this script uses window.external.notify('some string'); in javascript and in our script we have  top.location.href.

```
public sealed partial class Scenario6 : Page
{
    // A pointer back to the main page.  This is needed if you want to call methods in MainPage such
    // as NotifyUser()
    MainPage rootPage = MainPage.Current;

    public Scenario6()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        string src = "ms-appx-web:///html/scriptNotify_example.html";
        webViewLabel.Text = string.Format("Webview: {0}", src);
        webView6.Navigate(new Uri(src));
        webView6.ScriptNotify += webView6_ScriptNotify;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }


    void webView6_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Be sure to verify the source of the message when performing actions with the data.
        // As webview can be navigated, you need to check that the message is coming from a page/code
        // that you trust.
        Color c = Colors.Red;

        if (e.CallingUri.Scheme =="ms-appx-web")
        {
            if (e.Value.ToLower() == "blue") c = Colors.Blue;
            else if (e.Value.ToLower() == "green") c = Colors.Green;
        }
        appendLog(string.Format("Response from script at '{0}': '{1}'", e.CallingUri, e.Value), c);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper to create log entries
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logEntry"></param>
    void appendLog(string logEntry, Color c)
    {
        Run r = new Run();
        r.Text = logEntry;
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(c);
        p.Inlines.Add(r);
        logResults.Blocks.Add(p);
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs of the webView_NavigationStarting method should contains the link to where you are navigating. It should contain a Cancel property that if setted to true will prevent the webview to navigate to that link.

Comment: Yes i know that but it doesnt get called when i click on the button inside the web page